# How can I get DDL for a given Oracle package's "public" procedures?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ddl

I have a large number of Oracle packages. I'd like to write a query that allows me to create a list of where a handful of common problems can be found within those packages.

**What I've tried so far**

- I know I can isolate package arguments by querying `dba_arguments`
- I know I can find lines of code by querying `dba_source`
- I know I can identify procedures that appear on a package's spec by querying
  `DBA_Procedures`

I can join the first two sets of results together, but I'm having trouble joining the third set of results.

**How can I get DDL for procedures that appear on a given package's spec?**

Comment: dba_source is just the lines of code as they were in the source file, whereas the others are the result of compliation.  I think you are going to have great difficulty joining them because you basically need to compile the source to know the procedure name and arguments.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Please show an example of what you are talking about.  Thanks,.

Comment: Depends on what you call public (e.g. are you refering to public synonyms or just the package's specification).  In general, if you have the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE, you could invoke the dbms_metadata.get_ddl function.

Comment: Have you looked at dbms_metadata.get_ddl?

Comment: For a package's spec, you could do something like this (assuming the right privileges have been granted), `SELECT   dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE_SPEC','ACCOUNT_MGR','APPS')
FROM dual;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('PACKAGE', 'YOURPACKAGENAME', 'YOURSCHEMA') from dual;
```